# how do i implement doinbackground callback method

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, callback

my application started crashing after the implementation of google maps into a separate tab in my android application. i have looked through all other classes and logcat and deemed those classes to lightweight to be causing this issue.

here is my maps class

```
public class FragmentShouts_Maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment shouts.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshouts_maps, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
    if (fragment!= null) {
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap) {

}

}
```

i've noticed when i use an emulator with a lower dpi and without google play my application will make it to this tab but will be stopped and ended. on newer api(23) with google play services it wont even make it that far, once i swipe away from the home tab, it becomes unresponsive and ends.

i have no error codes so should work once i implement the doinbackground method i believe i just dont understand how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whats wrong with your code but I implemented google maps in my app and it works just fine. See if this is the kind of doInBackground implementation you are looking for. Hope this helps.

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map){
        // Your Code
        AsyncTask<String,Void,String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>(){
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // Do Something
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
                // Do Something
            }
        };
        asyncTask.execute(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u using android support v4

Comment: No i believe it is com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
You also need to include this in your dependencies `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0`